# Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) when changing multiple cell simultaneously

Tags: excel, vba

I have this simple VBA to record when task was started and when it was completed.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim cell As Range

If Target.Column = 3 Then
    For Each cell In Target.Cells

        If Target.Cells = "IN PROGRESS" And Target.Cells.Offset(0, -2).Value = "" Then
            Target.Offset(0, -2) = Format(Now(), "DD-MM-YYYY")

        ElseIf Target.Cells = "DONE" And Target.Offset(0, -1).Value = "" Then
            Target.Offset(0, -1) = Format(Now(), "DD-MM-YYYY")

        End If
    Next cell
End If

End Sub
```

Sheet looks like:

[image]

It works perfectly when changing cells one by one.

However, if I try to paste "DONE" in multiple cells, I get the "Type 13 Error mismatch" and VBA does not execute.

[image]

Anyone knows a simple way to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use a for each loop where you go through all the cells in the `Target.cells`. However you use `target.cells` inside the loop to check.

If you change your references in the loop from `target.cells` to `cell` it should fix your code.

Another note, it can benefit you if you use `cell.value`. This way you only make a check on the value in the cell.

```
For Each cell In Target.Cells

    If cell.value = "IN PROGRESS" And cell.Offset(0, -2).Value = "" Then
        cell.Offset(0, -2).value = Format(Now(), "DD-MM-YYYY")

    ElseIf cell.value = "DONE" And cell.Offset(0, -1).Value = "" Then
        cell.Offset(0, -1).Value = Format(Now(), "DD-MM-YYYY")

    End If
Next cell
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks!